# Sending rabbitMQ events after transaction commit

Tags: spring, hibernate, rabbitmq, spring-transactions

I have big task in transaction (@Transactional method). In this task the id-s are collected and then after transaction commit they must be sent to RabbitMQ (with convertAndSend-method). The RabbitMQ-listener in the other side takes the ids and updates the statuses in DB (it's important to update statuses after transaction changes because only after them the updated data is actual)
I have next questions:

1. What is the best way to use like the hook in the end (commit) of transaction? I need make the one "afterCommit" method for several service classes (many transactional-methods);
2. What need I use as the storage of ids? I have thought about smth like ThreadLocal variable but this is not a variant - if there is the parallelStream, the new Thread is created;
3. May be some other solution?

I have read about the delay RabbitMQ plugin but it is not the variant 4 my task - their time is very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the tags in your question I suppose you are using the spring framework.

So you could use **Spring Events** and its [ApplicationEventPublisher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisher.html) to publish your specific [ApplicationEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent.html) together with all the necessary data (the ids in your case).

Spring allows you to bind an event listener to a phase of the current transaction. Just use the *@TransactionalEventListener* annotation on a method that sends the data to RabbitMQ finally. Binding is possible to different transaction phases. With the default binding (AFTER_COMMIT) the event will only be fired if the transaction has completed successfully.

This Baeldung article on [Spring Events](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) is a nice place to find more detailed information.